# ADO _ConnectionPtr parameters

Tags: c++, ado

I'm trying to connect to my SQL server from a c++ console app. and 
this line of code drives me insane:

```
pConnection->Open("Server=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Database=WAWI;User ID=Test;   Password=Test;Trusted_Connection=False;","Test","Test",-1);
```

According to VS I'm supposed to provide the follwing information : (connectionstring,userID,pwd,longoption);
The connection string I can find at eg http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 and it should be possible to find the right one...but:

If I for example use the string above and provide both username and pwd in the string, do I still have to provide it as the second and third parameter or can i leave them empty?
And where can I find information about the last parameter "longoption"? What is it?

Thank you for your help,

Lumpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass empty strings as the 2nd and 3rd parameters if you provide this information in the connection string.

```
pConnection->Open("Server=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Database=WAWI;User ID=Test; Password=Test;Trusted_Connection=False;","","",-1);
```

Here is a how to [tutorial](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4033/using-ado-in-c/) on ado with c++.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have had a look at the tutorial you recommended and tried it out. Have you tried it? I have trouble with the ADODB namespace, it is not recognized. Even if I try to use rename_namspace("ADODB") it does not work. Do I have to change some settings in VS to make it "find" the namspace?   Lumpi

Answer (score 0):

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDBName;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=.
```

is OK too.